# SimpleDateFormatter Android Studio

Tags: java, android, время

пытаюсь спарсить дату вида "25.10.1999", но в итоге имею "25.10.1999 00:00 Oct ...", в массиве дат строковые представления. Как решить такую проблему? Заранее благодарю)

```
GraphView graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
            series = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>();
            for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
                try{
                series.appendData(new DataPoint(format.parse(data.get(i).trim()), value.get(i)), true, 500);
                }
                catch (ParseException e)
                {
                    System.out.println("Это не должно произойти");
                }
            }

            graph.addSeries(series);
```

Comment: "В итоге имею" где? Форматируйте при выводе в нужный формат (дд.мм.гггг?) и не будет никаких 00:00.

Comment: Там где format.parse, при дебаге выдает уже не то, что нужно.

Comment: Конечно, там выдает не то, что нужно. Там выдает экземпляр SimpleDateFormat, который включает в себя дату и ВРЕМЯ (т.к. в исходных данных время не указано, то ставится 00:00). Вам нужно перед appendData отформатировать представление даты в нужный формат для вывода.

Comment: А как форматировать дату, если не через SimpleDateFormat?

Comment: Так вы и не форматируете нигде. Вы только парсите. У библиотеки GraphView есть свой [форматтер дат для оси Х](http://jjoe64.github.io/GraphView/javadoc/com/jjoe64/graphview/helper/DateAsXAxisLabelFormatter.html), кстати.

Comment: Мне нужно сохранить переменную не стринговую. Если у вас есть ссылки на похожие примеры, не могли бы предоставить их?)

Comment: Непонятен вопрос. Сохранить переменную (куда?) это одно, а вывести ее на графике - совсем другое. Это разные задачи и одна с другой почти не связана.